# print string after keyword python

Tags: python, regex, string, file

I managed to pull the following line from the txt file

```
05/19/2014, 15:24:14.455> LVL:2 RC:   0          SERVER :server main: TERA_MGMT_SYS_SESS_EVENT_RESET with disconnect cause (0x105)
```

how to pull out `105` from it now?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, re, os
lineContains = re.compile('.*disconnect cause.*')
lineContainsCode = re.compile("^cause: (\w+)", s)
filename = open("pcoip_server_2014_05_19_00000560.txt", 'r')
for line in filename:
    if lineContains.match(line):
        print 'The file has: '
        print line
    if lineContainsCode.findall(line):
        print 'The code is:'
else:
    print 'The discoonect code not found.'
filename.close(
```

)
i tried to strip it but I am new to regex and bad at it any help would be appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a non regex approach:

```
code = line.split("(")[-1].split(")")[0].split("x")[-1]
# more readable:
# code = line.split("(")[-1]
#            .split(")")[0]
#            .split("x")[-1]
```

This will split the string on all the literal open parens, and index on `-1` (i.e. grab the last one). Then split that on all literal close parens, and index on `0` (i.e. grab the FIRST one), then split on all literal `"x"`s and index on `-1` (i.e. grab the last one)

```
KEY: ---- items not selected
     ++++ items selected
       |  split point (NOT SELECTED)

1.
05/19/2014, 15:24:14.455> LVL:2 RC:   0          SERVER :server main: TERA_MGMT_SYS_SESS_EVENT_RESET with disconnect cause (0x105)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|++++++

2.
0x105)
+++++|--

3.
0x105
-|+++
```

Resulting in `105`

EDIT HASHMAP EXAMPLE:

```
code = lineContainsCode.search(line).group(1)
hashmap = {"001":'PCoIP session terminated due to lost network.',
           "100":'PCoIP connection not established due to failure of PCoIP server initialization. This should not occur. Please contact Teradici support.',           
            ...
           "407":'PCoIP connection not established due to the View Security Server detecting that AES encryption is disabled on either the client and/or server.'}
error_msg = hashmap.get(code,'code not found in KB.')
print(error_msg)
```

Comment: i used this and it printed out **0x105**, is there any way just to pull out 105. I and really bad at it and would you mind in breaking it down or explaining please @Adam Smith

Comment: 'code = lineContainsCode.search(line).group(1)
       print code
       if code == '150':
        {
         print ('see kb')
        }' **trying to use if but does not seem to work and give me error saying**: File "pcoip_disconnect_codes.py", line 17
    print ('see kb')
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @user3731311 how long have you been writing python? Don't use curly braces to indicate code blocks....

Comment: not too long, i tried removing {}too. after getting code i tried **'if code == 150: print 'use this''** does not seem to work@Adam Smith thank you for all your help

Comment: @user3731311 it's hard to say without seeing your complete code :)

Comment: **#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, re, os

lineContains = re.compile(r'(?=.*disconnect cause)')
lineContainsCode = re.compile(r'cause\s*\(.*?(\d+)\)')
filename = open ("pcoip_server_2014_05_19_00000560.txt", 'r')

for line in filename:
    if lineContains.match(line):
       print 'The file has: '
       print line
       code = lineContainsCode.search(line).group(1)
       print 'The code is:', code
       if code == 150: 
         print 'jnjk'
       elif code ==151:
         print 'see thos'
    
filename.close()** here is the code @Adam Smith thank you

Comment: @user3731311 since indentation is meaning in Python, it's important that all your tabs are in the right spots and that's impossible to tell in a comment.

Comment: i have my codes uploaded up @Adam Smith thank you for your help

Comment: @user3731311 the traceback tells you everything you need to know. In your code the indentations are off somewhere. Also be aware that you'll never actually match anything this way because you're trying to match the number `100` not the string `"100"` and etc

Comment: @user3731311 also the pythonic way to deal with this would be a hashmap. I'll edit my code with an example.

Comment: I checked all the indentation and all but could not fix it. indentation looks good..

Comment: @user3731311 As the error message details: your indentation is NOT good :). There's not that many lines of code, check each one individually in your source code. Something's wrong with it. I edited now with a hashmap example.

Comment: thank you @Adam Smith, can you upload up the hashmap example please

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex to get the numbers inside `()` paranthesis. The below regex contain the string `cause` because it would helpful to correctly match the exact line and also the numbers within `()`.

```
cause \(.*?(\d+)\)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kM6uG5)

[image]

Your code would be,

```
lineContainsCode = re.compile(r'cause \(.*?(\d+)\)')
```

Comment: 'code = lineContainsCode.search(line).group(1)
       print code
       if code == '150':
        {
         print ('see kb')
        }' **trying to use if but does not seem to work and give me error saying**: File "pcoip_disconnect_codes.py", line 17
    print ('see kb')
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax @Rakesh KR